# docker compose version 2 recreates container when it should not

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose version 2 and I'm trying to create containers and attach them to a specific custom network. My ultimate goal is to create bundles of applications where each bundle will have a different suffix at the container name and network name. Every container with the same suffix will attach to the network with the same suffix.

I'm creating and running the containers with `docker-compose up`. The first time everything works great. The second time, now using a different suffix so the container names are different, instead of creating and running the new containes, docker compose will recreate the old containers (that had different names). Everything else is the same, except for the name which I thought would be enough. I thought of using `run` instead of `up` but the `depends_on` is not working and the `container_name` is not working either.

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1347

Versions:

`Docker version 1.13.0-rc2, build 1f9b3ef`

`docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387`

Comment: What about `docker-compose up --no-recreate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well i have done the similar kind of thing but i have used project name insisted of suffix.

you can specify project_name(or prefix) by -p option in docker-compose

`docker-compose -p project1 up`

It will create all container with project1_container_name_count and network with project1_network_name

now u can launch multiple container in same network (like different container using same DB) and they will be separated by suffix_count
like project1_app1 project1_app2